# How to switch MongoDB database on the fly while using db.collection.insert()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongo-shell, mongoid4

I have a multi-domain Rails 4 app where the `request.domain` of the http request determines which functionality I expose a given visitor to.

Each domain in my app should be served by its own MongoDB database. E.g. **domain1.com** is served by **db_for_domain_1**, etc.

I can read in the [MongoDB docs on runtime persistence](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#runtime-persistence-options) that

```
Mongoid.override_database("db_for_#{request.domain}")
```

enables me to switch database on the fly.

But how do I keep the persistence when I bypass Mongoid and use the mongo Shell method [db.collection.insert()](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)? I will still do it from within my application though.

The answer might be in the [MongoDB docs on collection access](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#client-and-collection-access), but I don't understand it. So how do I switch database before/during this operation?:

```
MyModel.collection.insert({field_1: "Value 1", field_2: "Value 2"})
```

Comment: Do you use the same model across the databases?

Comment: Yep, I do! I us the exact same models.

Comment: On "...how do I keep the persistence...": An ODM cannot know about operations made outside of that framework. When you insert the doc through the mongo shell command, trigger a read on that doc through Mongoid to load it into the persistence layer.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly: you have an app that connects to different mongodbs on different servers, but want to use mongo shell to connect to the database outside of your application? If true, you would connect to the desired database through the shell with

```
mongo db_for_domain_1:<port>/<dbName>
```

and then

```
db.<collectionName>.insert({doc})
```

see `mongo --help` for username and password options.

Comment: Thanks @SteveTarver. I'm very glad that it is possible to switch the database. I'm not quite sure though how to interpret this line: `mongo db_for_domain_1:<port>/<dbName>`. Is `mongo` the Ruby method, and `db_for_domain_1:<port>/<dbName>` a key,value argument? In that case I understand the value part of the argument (could e.g. be the port `27017`), but I don't understand the key part of the argument.

Comment: Oh sorry, no I want to connect from within my application. The only thing I want to circumvent is Mongoid (because I am using a mongo Shell method). So I need something that works e.g. from a controller.

Comment: Sorry, no rails or Mongoid experience, can't offer help there. Good luck though, sounds like an interesting challenge.